# How to make Samsung Galaxy SL I9003 play AC3?

Tags: audio, media-player

I have a film in the .AVI format, with an SRT subtitle file, and an AC3 audio track.

I used the S/W decoder function.

The film can be played with/without the subtitles, and the AC3 file itself can be played. I have tried MX player (not PRO) with the ARMv7 codec and VPlayer with the ARMv7 codec. I have the same problem on my Nook Color. If I stop the film and try to select audio, I have the only item which means embedded audio track.

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that you have 3 files (.avi, .srt & .ac3 (maybe some other language)) which you want to simultaneously play or is the ac3 track embedded in the avi? I'd say: Use [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to merge all into a single playable (.mkv or so) file for your handset.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your workaround! If you want, you can compile this into an answer, just FYI.

Comment: Thanks. (PS: The answer section is below... Sorry for nitpicking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution.**

I ended up preferring films in the .MKV format and using mkvmerge for merging audio tracks and subtitles into a video file.

**However,**

for those who want to watch films with an *embedded* AC3 audio track, [this solution](http://www.gimmickmag.com/how-to-restore-mx-player-audio-codec-ac3-dts-support/) could be useful. It worked on my [Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 SM-T530NU](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-T530NZWAXAR), and I'm sure it would work on any other device.